# Add a button to the tour

Tags: feature-request, tour

I just went back and took the tour of SE, just like a beginner might.

After a brief (and very good) description, there are two buttons that newbies can use to start to look at the hot questions or the areas.  But there is no button to get to learning more about such things as how to sign up as a user, or how to log into an area.

Admittedly, this material is premature for someone who just wants to get a feel for SE before getting involved.  But I still think it would be good to provide the button for people who want to go in that direction.

EDIT: I voted to delete this shortly after posting it, but so far it hasn't gone away.  I forgot that people don't sign into SE itself, but into one of the areas.  If I had remembered that, I would not have posted it.

Comment: There is a button for the [help]. What specifically do you think it should link to?

Comment: "area" is known more as "site" or "community".

Answer (score 7):

Have you *tried* signing up or logging into an area? Stack Exchange is designed to learn about these features as you *discover* them through a "just-in-time learning" experience.

You nailed exactly *why* it works this way right here:

> this material is premature for someone trying to get a feel for SE

I agree. So rather than hitting you with (literally) hundreds of buttons to learn about endless features before you even use the site, Stack Exchange spreads that guidance *throughout* the user experience so you can learn this stuff just as you need it.

My recommendation is to go ahead and *use* the site. Enjoy it. The guidance about how to use *"what comes next"* will help you through that process. But if you are really anxious to learn about *everything* before you use any of it, we have an extensive [**Help Center**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help) linked to the top of every page you can crawl through at your leisure — you've got a lot of reading ahead of you <grin> — but if that doesn't satiate your appetite for digging into this stuff, you are currently reading a huge [meta support site](http://meta.stackexchange.com) which discusses (in excruciating detail) just about every possible interface and issue you can imagine. So feel free to click on the 'Questions' or the 'Tags' button at the top of this site and dig in.

Good luck, and enjoy!